# @"" versus [NSString string]

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to work out the pros and cons of `@""` and `[NSString string]` as they appear to behave in a similar fashion.  I guess I'm hoping `[NSString string]` returns a static value thus avoiding unnecessary string creation in memory.  Can anyone shed some light as the documentation is inconclusive.

Comment: Just to add to the answer below.  Once the literal value @"Foo" is compiled.  Any other @"Foo" literals will be pointers to the first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite probable that `@"" == [NSString string]` and therefore the decision is just a matter of style. Aha, it’s not:

```
NSLog(@"%i", @"" == @""); // 1
NSLog(@"%i", [NSString string] == [NSString string]); // 1
NSLog(@"%i", [[NSString string] stringByAppendingString:@"foo"] ==
             [@"" stringByAppendingString:@"foo"]); // 1
NSLog(@"%i", @"" == [NSString string]); // 0
```

But I can’t think of any use case where the difference would matter.

Comment: +1 *but* your second line proves the OP's hope. the fourth is not relevant (here). `[NSString string]` returns foundation's literal or static, and `@""` returns the literal exported by your image. it would be relevant if the OP  needed to compare pointers, but that's not a requirement here. `@""` would be the fastest, but most people would not care about the speed difference. if the OP had a lot string comparisons to do and pointer comparisons were a good fit, then the result of `[NSString string]` may be faster.

Comment: If the fourth line was true, I think the discussion would be mostly moot, that’s why I have included it. Thanks for the clarifications!

Answer (score 2):

`@""` is a literal string and will exist throughout the execution of the application. `[NSString string]` is probably a dynamically allocated object (but may be optimized to not be) and so could (in theory) be collected during execution when no longer referenced. Both literal strings and dynamically allocated ones employ sharing internally, so two `@""` or two `[NSString string]` are likely to return the same object - even if not in the same file - but there is no guarantee that they will. However they may not return the same object as each other.

Overall it doesn't matter, you should not rely on pointer equality for testing string equality.

Looking at the assembly code I'd guess `@""` has the performance edge, but thinking that is important is really a case of premature optimization.

Just use `@""`, it has the merit of being short and clear.

Comment: I don’t think Rob wants to compare strings using pointers, that was just my test to discover the optimizations hidden behind different string constructors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure `[NSString string]` is simply a convenience method for `[[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease]`, which is identical to `@""` in semantics.

Which means there is no memory benefit whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

@"" is used to empty an NSString.
string is used to empty an NSMutableString.

```
NSString * string = @"String";
NSMutableString * mutablestring;
[mutablestring setString:@"Mutable String"];

NSLog (@"%@", string);        // String
NSLog (@"%@", mutablestring); // Mutable String

string = @"";
mutablestring = [NSMutableString string];

NSLog (@"%@", string);        // empty, nothing actually prints in NSLog
NSLog (@"%@", mutablestring); // empty, nothing actually prints in NSLog

//The below statement gives warning.
mutablestring = @"";
```

Answer (score 0):

@"" is a constant string,so -retain, -release, and -autorelease messages to them are ignored. Also it cannot be deallocated.
[NSString string] is already autoreleased.

Comment: `[NSString string]` is also special with respect to memory management (in the current implementation by Apple), see its retain count.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one thing here that matters, to me: That what I'm using is a truly empty string. *Every single time* I see `[NSString string]`, I am 100% guaranteed to get a string with a `.length` of `0`.

However, when I see `@""`, I am not 100% sure it's empty. Now, 99.9999%, that's a safe bet, but it could just as easily be `@"​"` ([zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)), [backspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace), [zero-width non-joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner), etc. Hopefully, the sadistic coder who used this put a comment near it saying that it's a zero-width space, but just so my code isn't so confusing, I use `[NSString string]`.